# How to make tmux messages stay longer?

Tags: tmux

For example, when I type a ***wrong*** command like `swap-window -c 1 -d 0` tmux shows me an error which in this case is:

```
Usage: swap-window [-d] [-s source-window] [-t dest-widnow]
```

However it's only for a split second and it disappears almost immediately.
Often I have to run the wrong command multiple times in order to read it or refer to the manual.

So Is there I way I can make messages like this stay for longer so I would be able to read them?

Comment: Alternately, you may view older messages using `<prefix>:show-messages`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change the time for all your tmux sessions, you can edit your *.tmux.conf* file and add:

```
set-option -g display-time 4000
```

The above command will change the default 750 milliseconds to 4000 (4 sec).
If you want to change the display time for a single session, then in your session, using the prefix `:` you can add:

```
set-option display-time 4000
```

(Also, setting to `0` will result in staying message forever, until any key press.)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for!